# SQL server backup issue - locked file

Tags: sql-server, backup, blocked, maintenance-plan

We have standart maintenance BACKUP plan

Task of backup has verifyonly option enabled.

During perfroming of backup we have failed job because VERIFYONLY task failed because of backup file was holded by another process. If I grub code from maintenance plan for any specific db(backup operation + restore verifyonly ) and run it manualy from query window this also failing with same error. If I add delay in two minutes between backup and restore verifyonly then i get no errors. This looks like something locking backup file right after creation and does not allow to run verifyonly. I have downloaded Process Monitor and tried to check activity for backup file , there is nothing except System , sqlserver.exe , and explorer.exe processes that touching the file.Did someone faced with this issue previously ?

Comment: off-topic - belongs on dba. Perhaps a virus scanner is causing the problem? Don't assume that only one machine is involved if the backup directory is not local or is accessible to other machines.

Comment: Nothing touch this file , only SYSTEM , SQLSERVR.EXE, explorer.exe , no any anticirus proccess touched the file.